# AngularJS - ui router - Cannot match url param key with exclamation mark

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have multiple states in my app, which i define using a $stateProvider like this:

```
.state(STATES.s1,
  {
    url: "/?refnr"
    template: ...
  })
.state(STATES.s2,
  {
    url: "/?details&searchID&pos"
    template: ...
  })
```

Now i want to have a third state, where i want to catch all the urls **containing a specific url param, which includes an exclamation mark**. This is the parameter **'emp!'** and looks like this in url with a value ".../?emp!=45".
I defined this as my state:

```
.state(STATES.s3,
  {
    url: "/?emp!"
    template: ...
  })
```

Does not work. It does not match the url.. I also tried to use a [$urlMatcherFactoryProvider](https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/docs/2.0.0/classes/url.urlmatcherfactory.html) and supply a compiled matcher as url, but same result. 
I also tried to use the encoded version of ! in my state url definition like this:

```
url: "/?emp%21"
```

still same result.

Why is that so? How can i match these urls?

Comment: What does STATE object contains ? (i.e STATE.s1, STATE.s2 etc). Is it supposed to be .state(
  {
    url: "/?refnr"
    template: ...
  })

Comment: i think you miss the point.. my state definition works. i just cannot match a url with that pattern.

Comment: Okay, got it. I tried with this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geekcode/p2rd83c5/1/). It works fine with url's with ! mark

Comment: i think that is working because of the linking with href..  A direct call to this url does not open this state.. i unfortunately cannot make a direct url call in your fiddle

Comment: but your fiddle is strange.. it still calls the 2. state when u change the href to this: <a href="#!/about/"   (without the parameter)

Comment: I tried with direct url's , it is working fine. You can just copy and run the html in your local browser. try and let me know.

Comment: i have found the reason why it works in your fiddle.. you have an extra path in your url definition: /about/?emp!   why?  As i wrote aboe, i want "..to catch **all urls** containing a specific url param".. so when i change your fiddle to this: /?emp!  it does not work. look here: https://jsfiddle.net/0cmy24vb/

Comment: what does STATES.s3 contains ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201561/discussion-between-akcasoy-and-allabakash).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick of fake parameter as this sample and this will handle all your urls ending with "/?emp!

```
.state(STATES.s3,
  {
    url: "/:anyurl/?emp!"
    template: ...
  })
```

Comment: i have tried with a "path" as you suggested, but it does not work. First of all, you always need a path, so i cannot match the urls without a path (i.e. "host"/?emp!).. secondly, the state s3 is also called when you do not have the exclamation mark like this: "host/path/?emp"

Comment: @akcasoy did you see the fiddle I made? that is not a path but a pathparam, which means /:any/anythingyouneed can be any path, you handle only final part as you need.
https://jsfiddle.net/pmc0gt3v/

Comment: i do not want to have an extra path-param.. i want to match all urls with this specific param. So remove this extra part from your about url like this: <a href="#!/?emp!">About</a>   it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. The expression between curly braces is a regular expression matching your criteria.

```
.state(STATES.s3, {
  url: "/{^\?.*emp!$}"
  template: ...
})
```

That regex will match urls that start with the `?`, ends with `!` and has `emp` before `!`. like:

- ?hemp!
- ?param=value&temp!

Comment: Can you build a demo app where this can be tested? I just answer as orientation, not a tested solution.